# IdentityServer4 with Windows authentication and custom claims

Tags: identityserver4

I have a problem with windows auth and custom claims.
I have an identityServer with windows auth and User.Identity.Name show my AD name.
But I cannot understand, how should I add some properties from my storage to this user. I have now something like this:

```
var claims = new List<Claim> {
      new Claim("devhomepage", "www.devsite.com", ClaimValueTypes.String)};
var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "siteinfo");
User.AddIdentity(userIdentity);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(User);
return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

and it doesn't work :-) my client will be not authorized.

here is a config for the server

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "mvc",
                    ClientName = "MVC Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:60640/signin-oidc"},// where to redirect to after login
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"http://localhost:60640/signout-callback-oidc"},// where to redirect to after logout
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    RequireConsent = false
```

and is't a client

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:49245/";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ClientId = "mvc";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SignIn I must use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager class with method SignInAsync(/*I should take hire a TUser object, that I stored in my database, and make mapping with my AD account */)

To use custom claims (will be used for all samples with custom claims in IS4):

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        protected UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public ProfileService(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            //>Processing
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);
            //my custom claims
            var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("devhomepage", "www"),
                    new Claim("reporting","reps")
                };

            context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
        }

        public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            //>Processing
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

            context.IsActive = (user != null);
        }
    }
```

But this service I must register only after my IdentityService

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
...
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
}
```

of ConfigureServices